# Удалить ссылки из списка

Tags: python, list

Есть список доменов

```py
a = ['*.abc.ru', '*.def.com', '*.qwery.ru']
```

И есть список ссылок

```py
b = ['http://abc.ru', 'http://def.com', 'http://qwery.ru']
```

из ссылок я могу получить домен

```py
for link in b:
    link.split('/')[2]
```

но как мне удалить из списка все ссылки, которые содержат домены из списка "a"?

Comment: а что за link.split('/')[2]? Сразу запустил и получил "name 'link' is not defined":-)

Comment: Что вы предприняли для решения проблемы?

Comment: @Сергей здесь имеется в виду отдельно взятый элемент массива b

Comment: @GreatTech, спасибо, чуть понятее, но в любом случае странный метод публикования кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял на выходе вы хотите иметь список со ссылками, у которых хосты не содержатся в списке `a`. Если это так, то держите вот это:

```py
a = ['*.abc.ru', '*.def.com', '*.qwery.ru']
b = ['http://abc.ru', 'http://def.com', 'http://qwery.ru', 'https://test.com', 'http://googgle.ru']

a_clear = [item.replace('*.', '') for item in a]

result = []

for item in b:
    flag = True
    for host in a_clear:
        if host in item:
            flag = False
    if flag:
        result.append(item)
```

Я делаю список с хостами без лишних знаков, затем пробегаюсь по спискам и нахожу совпадение, если такое существеут, то переменная `flag` принимает значение `False` и данные в результирующий список не попадают. Поскольку я добавил две ссылки с неопределенными хостами в `a`, то результат исполнения будет

```
>>> print(result)
['https://test.com', 'http://googgle.ru']
```

Здесь я создаю отдельную переменную `result`, куда помещаю необходимые данные. Почему так? Тип данных `list` - это изменяемый тип данных и если применять методы удаления в цикле, то могут появиться неожиданные результаты на выходе, поскольку длина списка и индексация будут меняться в течении работы этого цикла.

Если есть необходимость сохранить имя переменной `b`, то в конце работы скрипта определите следующее

```py
b = result[:]
```

То есть сделать копию списка `result` в `b`.

Answer (score 2):

при желании можно втиснуть все в одно списковое включение (list comprehension), примерно так:

```
a = ['*.abc.ru', '*.def.com', '*.qwery.ru']
b = ['http://abc.ru', 'http://def.com', 'http://qwery.ru', 'https://mail.ru', 'https://yandex.ru']

res = [i for i in b if not any(i.endswith(j[2:]) for j in a)]

>>> res
'''
['https://mail.ru', 'https://yandex.ru']
```